# DOCKER_HOST environment variable on windows

Tags: java, windows, maven, docker

I'm running Docker 1.12.0 on a Windows 10 machine. I'm developing a Java program, using Maven 3.3.9 as a dependency manager. I have a maven docker plugin (https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin), which gives the following error on clean install.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.15.16:build (docker-build-start) on project integration-test: Execution docker-build-start of goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.15.16:build failed: No `<dockerHost>` or `<machine>` given, no DOCKER_HOST environment variable, and no read/writable '/var/run/docker.sock' -> [Help 1]

When I run a clean install with the following configuration option in the POM file:

```
<dockerHost>tcp://0.0.0.0:2376</dockerHost>
```

the following result is shown.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.15.16:build (docker-build-start) on project integration-test: Cannot create docker access object: Cannot extract API version from server https://0.0.0.0:2376: Connect to 0.0.0.0:2376 [/0.0.0.0] failed: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]

My question: is there an IP address I can use to tell this maven plugin where it can reach the daemon? Normal docker commands work perfectly fine. The plugin works without any problems on OS X.

Comment: "Normal docker commands work perfectly fine." What's the variable set to then?

Comment: There is no variable, just ran the installer, and docker is added to the path variable. I can install containers an run them, I can list networks, list containers etc. Just the maven plugin complains about this variable.

Comment: See also https://github.com/fabric8io/shootout-docker-maven/issues/1

Answer (score 16):

After nearly a day of fruitless Googling I found this solution by myself. Trivial, but might still help others.

[image: expose Docker daemon]

You need to enable the checkbox 'Expose daemon on...' under Settings -> General

Comment: this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Thank you. This solved the following issue I was getting:
`error during connect: Get "http://127.0.0.1:2375/_ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Answer (score 12):

It seems the user which is running Maven goals doesn't have access to **docker.sock** . The error message is telling which options are there to resolve the problem.

> No `<dockerHost>` or `<machine>` given, no DOCKER_HOST environment
>   variable, **and no read/writable '/var/run/docker.sock**'

Last option is the easiest one because it requires a file permission and it doesn't need to create any docker machine or set a DOCKER_HOST, On Linux you can change read/write permission of docker.sock with the following:

```
sudo chmod 776 /var/run/docker.sock
```

On windows go through this article : [Microsoft article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/give-permissions-to-files-and-folders-in-windows/78ee562c-a21f-4a32-8691-73aac1415373)

Answer (score 11):

On Windows 10 with Docker for Windows, the Docker Engine API is available in these two locations:

- `npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine`
- `http://localhost:2375`

I recommend trying with the localhost one.

Details here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/#/how-do-i-connect-to-the-remote-docker-engine-api

Comment: On window 10 home it is not working on pro version that is valid <dockerHost>http://127.0.0.1:2375</dockerHost>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226315/failed-to-execute-fabric8-docker-plugin/46598043#46598043 

May be this link help you

Comment: @friism shouldn't `http` be `tcp` here?

Answer (score 2):

If someone **just wants to skip** the *optional* fabric8 docker-maven-plugin execution that prevents build to succeed with error

> No  given, no DOCKER_HOST environment variable, no
> read/writable '/var/run/docker.sock' or '//./pipe/docker_engine' and
> no external provider like Docker machine configured

then this can be achieved with `-Ddocker.skip=true` according to https://dmp.fabric8.io/#global-configuration.

Comment: Setting `docker.skip` doesn't solve the issue if the whole point is to be able to build with Docker!

Comment: @PeterDavis, as it was explicitly stated above, this answer is only for those who wants to fix the build but doesn't need the docker at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I tried to build a project in a custom GitLab CI/CD runner, with another than root user defined in a custom build image. I fixed by setting the read/write permission for users to the docker-socket.

```
chmod o+rw /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Window and Maven in eclipse to build your java project
but continue seeing that error, then you have to perform these steps:

Step1:

> You need to enable the checkbox 'Expose daemon on...' under Settings -> General
>   As mentioned by @Adriaan Koster

If step1 does not solve the issue,then

Step2: Run your eclipse in administration mode.
Now it should work without issues.

Answer (score -2):

use docker-machine if you are using toolbox.

```
            <machine>
                <name>default</name>
                <autoCreate>true</autoCreate>
                <createOptions>
                    <driver>virtualbox</driver>
                    <virtualbox-cpu-count>2</virtualbox-cpu-count>
                </createOptions>
            </machine>
```