# Failed to execute fabric8 docker plugin

Tags: docker, elastic-stack, fabric8

Running mvn clean install pulls up this error( Windows)

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.20.1:start     (prepare-environment) on project integration-test: Execution prepare-environment   of goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.20.1:start failed: Start-Job failed with    unexpected exception: [sebp/elk:latest] "elk": Timeout after 120365 ms while   waiting on url http://localhost:32774/

Comment: Please explain how you actually came to that issue (what commands did you ran ?) as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a dropwizard project with elastic search module, integration test module and the main project module, running mvn clean install gets the success for all the other modules and leaves the integration test with a failure message. and the error message I posted appears at eh bottom

Comment: As it stands this question cannot be answered. You need to supply at least the Maven file you're running so that we can see how you've configured the Fabric8 docker plugin. I could speculate that your issue is that you have configured container logging and that there is no elk stack listening on port 32774. (See: https://dmp.fabric8.io/#start-logging)